# How to make inline form elements responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Introduction**
Hi, i am working with the search form, having 5 inputs and a search button. Each input field have its label.

**Code**

```
<section class="content">
        <div class="box box-info">
            <form action="/users" id="Search-form" method="POST" role="form">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-inline row" role="form" style="padding-top: 7px; padding-left: 10px;width:100%;">
                        <div class="form-group frm-setp">
                            <label for="pwd">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="first name" name="name" id="srch-term" value="$data.name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group frm-setp">
                            <label for="pwd">Ph#:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="923325540106" name="phoneNumber" id="srch-term" value="$data.phoneNumber" pattern="[0-9]{12}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group frm-setp">
                            <label for="email">From:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control pickdate" name="fromdate" id="fromdate"
                                   value="$data.from" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group frm-setp">
                            <label for="pwd">To:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control pickdate" name="todate" id="todate"
                                   value="$data.to" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group frm-setp">
                            <label for="pwd">Filter</label>
                            <select name="ddlFilterBy" id="ddlFilterBy" class="form-control">
                                <option value="all">All</option>
                                <option value="driver">Active Drivers</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group frm-setp">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Display LG**
[image]
**Display MD**
[image]

**Problem**
Here, clearly i have problem with medium screens or less but works perfect with larger screens.
On medium or small screens, other elements break the line.

If someone have idea about this kind of problem or any reference, then please do help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: By making the inputs stay in single line, you are actually making it difficult for user to enter data in small screens... I suggest maintaining a minimum size for input fields...

Comment: @LiniSusanV Thanks for help, yes i understand the bad user experience for small, lets put it this way that i only care for medium and large screens.

Comment: Ok... Then you should go ahead and add `col-md-2 col-lg-2` classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in this way-- All your inputs must be wrapped within responsive grid column classes.

**Working example**

```css
@media(max-width:767px){
#srch {
margin-top: 22px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
         <style type="text/css">
         </style>
         </head>
         <body>
          <section class="content">
      <div class="box box-info">
          <form action="/users" id="Search-form" method="POST" role="form">
              <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="form-inline row" role="form" style="padding-top: 7px; padding-left: 10px;width:100%;">
                      <div class="form-group frm-setp col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                          <label for="pwd">Name:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="first name" name="name" id="srch-term" value="$data.name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group frm-setp col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                          <label for="pwd">Ph#:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="923325540106" name="phoneNumber" id="srch-term" value="$data.phoneNumber" pattern="[0-9]{12}">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group frm-setp col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                          <label for="email">From:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control pickdate" name="fromdate" id="fromdate"
                                 value="$data.from" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group frm-setp col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                          <label for="pwd">To:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control pickdate" name="todate" id="todate"
                                 value="$data.to" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group frm-setp col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                          <label for="pwd">Filter</label>
                          <select name="ddlFilterBy" id="ddlFilterBy" class="form-control">
                              <option value="all">All</option>
                              <option value="driver">Active Drivers</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group frm-setp col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                          <button id="srch" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, +1 for the effort. this makes now like this on medium screens https://flic.kr/p/R6d6WY

Comment: can you give margin-top and margin-left to position the search button

Comment: Check the updated snippet you can style for different screen sizes like this.

Comment: thanks for the help, i already set the margin. now design is fixed for lg and md

Answer (score 2):

Use `col-*-*` class for all your inputs and labels.

```
   <div class="col-*-*"> 
     <input class="input-lg">
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, +1 for the help about using grid system, but it won't work in my condition.